# What's an easy way to round out this castle wall?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

I'm really new to Blender, and I was trying to build a castle wall. The only way that I could figure out how to do that was with a bunch of cubes. I've built the castle, figured out how to animate the drawbridge, and added some not great color. Now I'm trying to figure out how to round out everything so that this tower thing looks more like a tower and less like a stack of cubes, and the window things to be kind of arched at the top, not just cubes. What's the best way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Blender is not like minecraft, you don't stack cubes to make objects. Watch a few videos on the internet that explain basic modelling techniques.

Comment: Also, it seems like you aren't aware of *edit mode* (shortcut tab) this mode lets you modify an existing object's geometry. The most basic shortcuts to create new geometry are E to extrude a face or CTRL + R to add a loop cut. You can also access these in the left hand panel. I suggest following along a few videos in the official blender channel on youtube to familiarize yourself with it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF1qEhBSfq4&list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don´t need to do that. Just use a cylinder for the tower. Select the upper face and extruded out to extend it a little and then extrude it up to give heigh.Make two loop cuts one outside and one inside the extruded faces to create a division for the up and down wall ( i don´t know the exact name of that part) Then jus select the faces you need to make the upper part of the tower and erase them. After that select the edges of the adjacent face and click on keyboard F to fill it with a face.[image]